Can I breed my and my friend's wolves?
Me and my friend both have a pup, and we were wondering if we could breed our dogs together. We are playing the Bedrock Edition. If anyone knows, please let us know!

Tamed wolves at full health can be bred with any type of meat, including rotten flesh and raw chicken.
Breeding two wolves that recognize someone else as an owner causes the pup to also be owned by the owner of the original two wolves. If two tamed wolves have different owners, their pups will randomly follow one of their two owners.
So, according to the last sentence, you should be able to do so.
Source, Minecraft Wiki.
